# XML parsing in Jquery with separate divs

Tags: jquery, xml

I have the following XML which I cannot adjust since it is thrown out from another system with the following xml tree:

```
<Parent>
   <Item
      picture = "test.png"
      text = "test test 1" />

   <Item
      picture = "test1.png"
      text = test test 2" />
</Parent>
```

basically the task is to find each item but to give each item a different div class and style therefore enabling them to be positioned in different places.

I have used the `.find('Item').each (function ()` but it obviously finds all the items and gives them the same properties, which is not what is requested. Is there a way of doing this and if so how? All constructive comments are appreciated.

Comment: Please post your JS/jQuery code and the html into which you want to append the data.

Comment: You missed to open double quotes before `test test 2`. And where is div which you are using in question. Can you make an online demo for it, or show us your full code to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `.parseXml()`

**Sample Jquery Code :**

```
 <script>
    var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $title = $xml.find( "title" );
    /* append "RSS Title" to #someElement */
    $( "#someElement" ).append( $title.text() );
    /* change the title to "XML Title" */
    $title.text( "XML Title" );
    /* append "XML Title" to #anotherElement */
    $( "#anotherElement" ).append( $title.text() );
</script>
```

**REF:http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/**

Happy Coding:)